# Streamlit with Tensorflow to analyse image and return the probability if is positive or negative

Tags: tensorflow, streamlit

I'm trying to use Tensorflow to Machine Learning to analyze an image and return the probability if is positive or negative based on a model created (extension .h5). I couldn't found a documentation exactly for that, or repository, so even a link to read will be awesome.

Link for the application: https://share.streamlit.io/felipelx/hackathon/IDC_Detector.py

Libraries that I'm trying to use.

```py
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
```

The function to load the model.

```py
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def loadIDCModel():
  model_idc = load_model('models/IDC_model.h5', compile=False)
  model_idc.summary()
  return model_idc
```

The function to work the image, and what I'm trying to see: model.predict - I can see but is not updating the %, independent of the image the value is always the same.

```py
if uploaded_file is not None:
    # transform image to numpy array
    file_bytes = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(uploaded_file, target_size=(96,96), grayscale = False, interpolation = 'nearest', color_mode = 'rgb', keep_aspect_ratio = False)
    
    c.image(file_bytes, channels="RGB")

    Genrate_pred = st.button("Generate Prediction")    
    if Genrate_pred:
         model = loadMetModel()
        input_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(file_bytes)
        input_arr = np.array([input_arr])
        probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])
        prediction = probability_model.predict(input_arr)
        dict_pred = {0: 'Benigno/Normal', 1: 'Maligno'}
        result = dict_pred[np.argmax(prediction)]
        value = 0
        if result == 'Benigno/Normal':
            value = str(((prediction[0][0])*100).round(2)) + '%'
        else:
            value = str(((prediction[0][1])*100).round(2)) + '%'
        
        c.metric('Predição', result, delta=value, delta_color='normal')
```

Thank you in advance to any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'm noticing is that your function for loading the model is named `loadIDCModel`, but then the function you *call* for loading the model is `loadMetModel`. When I check your [source code](https://github.com/felipeLx/hackathon/blob/ff9cc3ffb191089d86a09e1e1ee0b9038b73748b/IDC_Detector.py#L38), though, it looks like you've already addressed this issue. I'd recommend updating your question to reflect this.

Playing around with your application, I think the issue is your model itself. I tried various images — images containing carcinomas, and even a picture of a cat — and each gave me a probability around 73%. The lowest score I got was 72.74%, and the highest was 73.11% (this one was the cat). It seems that the output percentage is varying slightly, hinting that rather than something being wrong in the code, your model itself is likely at fault. You might need to retrain your model, as it seems to have learned to always return a value of approximately 0.73.